# ILMerge error: SQLite.Interop.dll [Could not load assembly from the location]

Tags: visual-studio

I'm currently writing a small app and I decided to use SQLite database.
I need 2 libraries to merge with ILMerge: SQLite.Interop.dll and System.Data.SQLite.dll

The problem is when I want to merge my exe with those DLLs.

When I try to merge them, there appears an error:
An exception occurred during merging:

```
ILMerge.Merge: Could not load assembly from the location 'C:\Program Files\Micro
soft\ILMerge\SQLite.Interop.dll'. Skipping and processing rest of arguments.
   w ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   w ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

What's more, when I merge the exe with System.Data.SQLite.dll, it works.
The problem is with SQLite.Interop.dll library.

I use .NET v4 [Visual Basic 2010].

I really need your help,
Regards.

Comment: You probably did not provide the path to this assembly in the command arguments.

Comment: What I type into commandline: 
ilmerge /targetplatform:v4,"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"  /target:winexe /out:out.exe in.exe System.Data.SQLite.dll SQLite.Interop.dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot work because the SQLite.interop.dll is not a managed assembly.

ILMerge can only read and combine managed assemblies into a new managed assembly. If you have to mix native dlls and managed assemblies you need to create either a setup/msi or a bootstrapper.