# ILMerge: What to do when a reference can't be added?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ilmerge

When I do

```
ilmerge /targetplatform:4 /out:Newconverter.exe converter.exe Newtonsoft.Json.dll  AWSSDK.dll ImageResizer.dll
```

I get:

```
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: Conaito.PPT2HTML5.
```

`Conaito.PPT2HTML5` is an assembly reference I have in my project, although it's not "installed" like the others. I had to browse to the location of the .dll in order to add it.

If I add the Conaito thing do my `ilmerge` command so that it reads:

```
ilmerge /targetplatform:4 /out:Newconverter.exe converter.exe Newtonsoft.Json.dll  AWSSDK.dll ImageResizer.dll Conaito.PPT2HTML5.dll
```

I get:

```
An exception occurred during merging:
ILMerge.Merge: Could not load assembly from the location '[path]\bin\Debug\Conaito.PPT2HTML5.dll'.
```

But the file clearly exists in that location.

Could this be the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026795/ilmerge-error-sqlite-interop-dll-could-not-load-assembly-from-the-location), where it's simply not possible because the thing I'm trying to load isn't a "managed assembly"?

In the case that it is completely impossible to ilmerge this .dll into the executable, what can I do so that I can actually build my project? This error is causing builds to fail.

Comment: You can try to open the conaito dll with ildasm.exe to check if its a managed or unmanaged dll.

Comment: @AbdullahNehir  I used ildasm.exe on the dll and it said that it was protected.

Comment: I would recommend using the ILMerge alternate method (linked on the ILMerge page): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx I have found this to be a _much_ better solution. This would likely eliminate your build issues since all the external references would be embedded into your EXE.

Comment: The error isn't obvious, you may try [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) instead (it has the same syntax so it should be a drop-in replacement) to see if its error (if any) is any cleaner.